# Submitting sandboxed MonoMac app without accessing shared memory?

Tags: mac-app-store, monomac

I have a Sandboxed MonoMac based application in the MacAppStore, with the latest update to the app pushed to MAS I received a message from Apple that the application accesses /dev/shm, and that this update will be allowed but future updates must not access /dev/shm. I'm not using any shared memory in my application so I'm assuming this is because parts of MonoMac is using Shared memory (which would make sense). How can I possibly work around this in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shared memory access is caused by the initialization of the performance counters when the `/dev/shm` folder is probed. An environment variable named `MONO_DISABLE_SHARED_AREA` has been introduced to avoid this. See the [mono-mmap.c](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/utils/mono-mmap.c) source file to learn more about it.

**Update**: [A bug on this variable](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12655) has been fixed in the 3.0 series.