# Mac App store rejection '/dev/shm'

Tags: macos, mono, monomac, mac-app-store, monobjc

I'm using monobjc to develop my mac application.  And after release to appstore it was rejected with message:

The application accesses the following location(s):

'/dev/shm'

Does anyone know how can I fix this issue?

**UPD:** I'm using - Mono 3.2.6, Monobjc 5.0.2165.0, Add-in 4.0.2167.11, Xamarin Studio 4.2.2

fs_usage utility shows such log

17:31:06  access            /proc>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                                         0.000007
17:31:06  access            /proc>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                                         0.000003
17:31:06  stat64            A/CoreFoundation                                                                 0.000016
17:31:06  mmap                                                                                               0.000007
17:31:06  close                                                                                              0.000002
17:31:06  open              /dev/shm                                                                         0.000018
17:31:06  mmap                                                                                               0.000006
17:31:06  close

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submitting sandboxed MonoMac app without accessing shared memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535456/submitting-sandboxed-monomac-app-without-accessing-shared-memory)

Comment: Can you post the version used ?

Comment: I'm using - Mono 3.2.6, Monobjc 5.0.2165.0, Add-in 4.0.2167.11, Xamarin Studio 4.2.2